# Calling self.navigationController from custom delegate results in null

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have an custom `UIScrollView` and I have created a custom `delegate` when clicking the footer of the cell and I want to start a `ViewController` when that happens..

```
- (void)cellFooterViewTapped:(NSInteger)index
{
ProfiliViewController *profiliView = [[ProfiliViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:profiliView animated:YES];
}
```

the index of the clicked cell is passed correctly so that means the method is being called.
It's just that `navigationController` doesn't work and I also NSLogged it and printed null.
What can it be? I have 4 other buttons on the main `ViewController` with this same code and it is not null.

This is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
ViewController *_switchviewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_switchviewcontroller];
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[[UISwitch appearance] setOnTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.204 green:0.286 blue:0.368 alpha:1.0]];
return YES;
// Override point for customization after application launch.
}
```

Also the NavigationController and Main ViewController are declared in the storyboard.
Everything else is code only.

Comment: can you show your `appDidFinishLaunching` code? so we can know your navigation stack.

Comment: I edited the post. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that you cant get the navigationController everywhere with this code

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method `- (void)cellFooterViewTapped:(NSInteger)index` should be in a `UIViewController` so that you can push a new `UIViewController` in its navigation controller.

Also, the current `UIViewController` should be pushed/added to an existing navigation controller stack. If the `UIViewController` is not added in `navigationController` yet, it will be null.

Comment: `- (void)cellFooterViewTapped:(NSInteger)index` is actually on my main `UIViewController` its the same class where I have 4 other buttons which push different ViewControllers without problems

Answer (score 0):

Your storyboard structure should look like below image. navigation controller must be your root controller.and connect mainview controller as root of navigation controller as shown in image. then you can push any controller. and you dont have to write any code in `appDidFinishLaunching` because everything is connect in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: I did and now I get blank screen when i open the app

Comment: again I get blank screen, I forgot to mention, my NavigationController and Main ViewController is declared on storyboard -_- cause some1 else started the project.

Comment: @Elgert oh ok. you should add that you are using Storyboard in your question.

Comment: This almost the same as what I have, 1 nav controller and 1 main view controller, and from there I only push with code. But only on this delegate `self.navigationController` is null

Comment: Have you remove code from `appDidFinishLaunching`? why you add `[self.window addSubview:navController.view];` ?

Comment: Yes I removed the code, It was empty initially but I saw here in SO you had to do that and I tried. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

you might have non `navigationController`.
You should push `self` in a `navigationController's` stack so that you can have a `navigationController`.

Comment: if you mean `[self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];` i tried and i Get this error **Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported**

Comment: NO. I mean that the viewController(self) whether in the navigation's stack. If the viewController(self) is now in a navigation stack, your problem can't happen, So, I just wanna to ensure where you have ever pushed the viewController(self).

Comment: There is anther problem about your writing way that may cause some warning when launched the application.   ViewController *_switchviewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_switchviewcontroller];
[self.window addSubview:navController.view]; you should use self.window.rootViewController = navController insteadof [self.window addSubview:navController.view];